# PHP - remove duplicate syllable word

Tags: php, regex, string, duplicates

i'm new and wanna know how to using regex in php.
if i have text like `"haha" "abcabcabc" "hehehe" "cupcupcupcup"` (contain duplicate of syllable word).

How to remove that text?

(say `$text="cupcupcup";`", how to make this like `$text="";`)

sorry if there is same ask (i have search, but cant find page that describe my issue)

thanks for your appreciate. :)

Comment: What if the string is `hahaabcabcabc`?

Comment: (contain duplicate of syllable word). How to remove that text?. perhaps in your text that will not contain anything

Comment: You mean that if you have `$text="cupcupcup";`, you should get `$text="";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$txt = preg_replace("/^(.*)(\\1+)$/", "", $txt);
```

This searches for a sequence at the start of the string, then matches at least one repetition of that string, then matches the end of the string.

e.g.

```
$txt = preg_replace("/^(.*)(\\1+)$/", "", "cupcupcup");  //=> ""
$txt = preg_replace("/^(.*)(\\1+)$/", "", "cucupcup");   //=> "cucupcup"
```

Comment: @HamZa It shouldn't since the next subpattern is required at least once (due to the `+` quantifier) before the end of the string.

Comment: print preg_replace("/^(.*)(\1+)$/", "", "sasa"); // => sasa, not "" :-(

Comment: @user4035 Sorry forgot to escape the backreference with a second `\\`, have updated the answer. Try again now!

Comment: @user4035 Please accept the answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: this would replace all kinds of word

Comment: @user2413763 You may want to look at Anirudh's answer as it expands on mine by restricting results to syllable matches only :)

Comment: @Graham Hi, if there is other string that codes not remove syllable. eg: $text="string beside cupcupcup string again"; how to repair the regex? if printed it will be "string beside string again"thanks :)

Comment: i find it, sory for my noobs. /(.*)(\\1+)/

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess this would do

```
\b(?=\w*[aeiou]\w*)(\w*)\1+
     -------------
           |
           |->check if its a syllable word
```

replace it with `""`

Comment: Right, I didn't catch the syllable word as a requirement, nice one.

Comment: @Graham refined your regex..:)

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I came up with:

```
([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz][aeiouy](?:[a-z])?|[aeiouy][b-df-hj-np-tv-xz](?:[a-z])?)(\1){2,}
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pR0jY6)

**Explanation:**

- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]` : Match consonants.
- `[aeiouy]` : Match vowels.
- `[a-z]` : Match a letter.
- `([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz][aeiouy](?:[a-z])?` : Match consonant followed by a vowel and optionally followed by a letter.
- `|[aeiouy][b-df-hj-np-tv-xz](?:[a-z])?)` : Or match a vowel followed by a consonant followed optionally by a letter.
- `(\1){2,}` : Repeat group 1 two or more times.

Answer (score 0):

if the text like :

```
$txt = preg_replace("/(.*)(\\1+)/", "", "the text is  cupcupcup and cupcupcupa");
```

that will remove `cupcupcup` and `cupcupcupa` . how to just remove `cupcupcup` ?

Comment: @Graham can you fix this problem?