# Can't remove repeating word syllable - PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, duplicates

Last day, I try to remove repeating word sylable like : `haha` `dadada` `wkwkwk` etc
I try use this : `preg_replace("/^(.*)(\\1+)$/", "", $text)`

Now, I get a problem. the case is, if :

1. `$text=haha` or `$text=wkwkwk`  ==> text in $text will be removed
2. `$text=text beside haha`   ==> text in $text is **intact.**

You can try this :

```
<?php
$txt = 'removed : '.preg_replace("/^(.*)(\\1+)$/", "", "hahaha").'<br>not remove : '.preg_replace("/^(.*)(\\1+)$/", "", "there is text beside hahaha");
echo $txt;
?>
```

My hope is I can remove repeating word syllable on text like $text in no.2.
So, output no.2 is `text beside`

Comment: Try to use my answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16884632/). Note that it won't match `haha`, but will match `hahaha`. You may ofcourse change the expression to `([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz][aeiouy](?:[a-z])?|[aeiouy][b-df-hj-np-tv-xz](?:[a-z])?)(\1){1,}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the hanchor

```
/(.*)(\\1+)/
```

if you want to not delete word like `lelet` use a word boundary:

```
/(.*)(\\1+)\b/
```

Comment: Hi @M42 , how about text like "lelet"? i dont want to remove "lelet". can you?